# How would I view what code is being executed when I use a certain function?

Tags: python

I am wondering what the print function does behind the scenes. How can I view the code that is executed when I use the print function in python, among other functions?

Comment: be more specific, list out some expected output

Comment: You could try searching it in your Python installation folder. Most of the code is accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learning how something in the standard library is implemented is a great way to learn about that language.

Unfortunately considerable parts of Python are implemented in C language which makes studying this parts less educational and more difficult.

The modules (the stuff you `import`) can be found in the filesystem and the Parts are easy to inspect. Try

```
import os.path
print(os.path.__file__)
```

This should show you the file where a certain module (for example `os.path`) is implemented.

To my vague memory `print` originates from a module called **builtins** and is implemented in C - but I might be wrong.

Basically it looks like this:

```
def print(*args):
    sys.stdout.write(''.join(args))
```

`sys.stdout.write` calls Operating System write function for the file handle `1` which is defined as stdout or "the screen'.

Answer (score 1):

you can user `Inspect`

your code should look like this

```
import inspect

inspect.getdoc(print)
```

Edit : not for something **being**